# Query every row of the table after joining it to another

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I built a SQL query to get all `property` addresses that are available for rent and not booked:

```
  select property.address
  from (period join booking on period.propertyid = booking.propertyid) join property on period.propertyid = property.id
  where period.type = 'available'
  AND period.end >= TO_DATE('2016-01-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND period.start <= TO_DATE('2016-01-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND (
    booking.start > TO_DATE('2016-01-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD') OR
    booking.start < TO_DATE('2016-01-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  )
  AND (
    booking.end > TO_DATE('2016-01-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD') OR
    booking.end < TO_DATE('2016-01-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  );
```

However because of `period join booking on period.propertyid = booking.propertyid` it doesn't query `periods` of `properties` (apartments) that doesn't exist in `booking` table.

How can I join `booking` table so that all `periods` are still queried?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select property.address
  from (
    period 
    left join booking on period.propertyid = booking.propertyid) 
...
```

Comment: Yes use left join, but base table should be property, not period

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT property.address
FROM property
LEFT JOIN period  ON period.propertyid = property.id
LEFT JOIN booking ON period.propertyid = booking.propertyid
WHERE period.type = 'available'
AND period.end   >= '2016-01-25'
AND period.start <= '2016-01-20'
AND (booking.start > '2016-01-25' OR booking.start < '2016-01-20')
AND (booking.end   > '2016-01-25' OR booking.end   < '2016-01-20')
```